# Have an array inside an array JQuery

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
var phyList = [
    {
    "firstName": "Michael",
    "lastName": "Abbey-Mensah",
    "status": "Courtesy",
    "specialty": "Pediatrics",
    "address": "4564454, Brooklyn, NY 11212",
    "phone": "718 || 718.385.9279"
    },
    {
    "firstName": "Niraj",
    "lastName": "Acharya",
    "status": "Active",
    "specialty": "Medicine",
    "address": "4545 Avenue, Jamaica NY 11432",
    "phone": "4545.558.2894 || 4545.558.9735"
    }
];
```

What if i wanted to have more than one specialty for the first entry?
Let's say **Pediatrics** and **Surgery**.

Will this work:

```
var phyList = [
    {
    "firstName": "Michael",
    "lastName": "Abbey-Mensah",
    "status": "Courtesy",
    "specialty": ["Pediatrics", "Surgery"],
    "address": "454545ergaston Blvd, Brooklyn, NY 11212",
    "phone": "745458.485.2704 || 516.385.9279"
    },
    {
    "firstName": "Niraj",
    "lastName": "Acharya",
    "status": "Active",
    "specialty": "Medicine",
    "address": "45459th Avenue, Jamaica NY 11432",
    "phone": "718.558.2894 || 718.558.9735"
    }
];
```

Comment: you could put them in an array: ["Pediatrics", "Surgery"]

Comment: it all depends on what you want to do with these objects...

Comment: Will this work? No, you've got invalid object literal syntax inside that array. Do away with the curly braces and just have an array of strings, as m7o suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain specialty values in an array:

```
var phyList = [
    {
    "firstName": "Michael",
    "lastName": "Abbey-Mensah",
    "status": "Courtesy",
    "specialty": ["Pediatrics ","Surgery"],
    "address": "437 Mothergaston Blvd, Brooklyn, NY 11212",
    "phone": "718.485.2704 || 516.385.9279"
    },
    {
    "firstName": "Niraj",
    "lastName": "Acharya",
    "status": "Active",
    "specialty": ["Medicine"],
    "address": "152-11 89th Avenue, Jamaica NY 11432",
    "phone": "718.558.2894 || 718.558.9735"
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I Suppose , you need to have a array like this then

```
var a = [{"id":"1","images":[{"img_id":"1"},{"img_id":"2"},{"img_id":"3"}]},
     {"id":"2","images":[{"img_id":"1"},{"img_id":"2"},{"img_id":"3"}]}];
```

where Images has an array of values for its entry

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
     "specialty": [
         "Pediatrics", "Surgery"
     ],
```

An array can hold many values under a single name, and you can access the values by referring to an index number.